# Status of form/profile usability

Tags: profile, webform-civicrm, forms, cms-integration, usability

Could someone give an update on the status of creating more usable form/profiles without using Drupal's Webform?  (Especially iin regards Wordpress but preferable CMS agnostic)

I'm certain I'm not the only WP user struggling with form creation that is annoyed with the 'use Webform' response to nearly every form/profile question. It seems obvious to me that this is a major usability issue with CiviCRM that has been avoided for years due to the crutch of Webform.

And yes, I have heard also of a mysterious gravity forms plugin (with a big annual fee to use it), but this just perpetuates one of the main flaws in your otherwise amazing system.

/rant.

Comment: since Webforms isn't likely to ever be upgraded for Drupal 8 then the lack of a core solution for this will also begin biting Drupal users most likely

Answer (score 1):

More usable forms/profiles is a major goal of CiviCRM 5.0.

Creating a form creator that's flexible enough to meet the varied needs of many constituencies is a lot of work.  Unfortunately, while CiviCRM is free to use, it's not free to write.  Most of the folks who complain aren't willing to fund (or do) the work.  Using Webform is certainly a crutch, but in a world without unlimited developer resources, you can understand why someone wrote the CiviCRM-Webform integration rather than try to do it all from scratch.

I have no way of knowing which camp you fall into - but for everyone with this same question who hasn't contributed, please consider [the](https://civicrm.org/become-a-member) [many](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=47) [ways](https://civicrm.org/work-with-the-core-team) in which you can help make more usable forms/profiles a reality.